# How can I make my blinking string also change values? (Python 3.5)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following piece of code in Python 3.5:

```
def blink(char):                       
    while 1:                               
        print (char, end = '\r')           
        time.sleep(0.5)                       
        print (' ' * 50, end = '\r')       
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

> I am using this function to make any string blink for a specific time

The problem is that when I use it in the code below it doesn't have the desired effect:

```
while True:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    seconds += 1
    if seconds == 60:
        minutes += 1
        seconds = 0
    if minutes == 60:
        hours += 1
        minutes = 0
    if hours == 24:
        days += 1
        hours = 0
    blink ('Days: %s, Hours: %s, Minutes: %s, Seconds: %s' % (days, hours, minutes, seconds))
```

> I'm using this piece of code to 'simulate' time. The problem is that the output looks like this:

```
Days: 0, Hours: 0, Minutes: 0, Seconds: 1
```

> This keeps on blinking on the same line as I want it to, but the problem is that the output doesn't increase.

```
e.g Days: 0, Hours: 0, Minutes: 0, Seconds: 2 etc.
```

Comment: you have an infinite while loop inside of your blink function and youre incrementing your data outside of the blink function so the blink function is only ever called once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `blink(char)` function does not end, so the `while True` loop will be stuck in its first cycle.

Try removing the while loop from the blink function to make it only blink once:

```
def blink(char):                       
    print(char, end = '\r')           
    time.sleep(0.5)                       
    print(' ' * 50, end = '\r')       
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

(Or create a separate `blink_once` function.)

Comment: Thanks, it's working now! I was using the function to print strings that won't change over time so I didn't notice the infinite loop problem.